# Cannot Set Property 'fontWeight' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Im trying to bold Student[i].club and I'm trying put a horizontal space between Student[i].gender and Student[i].grade. Each of the inputs goes into a div and displays in it. If the rest of the code is need I'll post that too if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

```js
    fieldann += Student[i].grade;
    fieldann += Student[i].gender;
    fieldann += Student[i].club;
    fieldann += Student[i].announcement;

    Student[i].grade.style.fontWeight = "900";

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "20%";
    div.style.height = "100%";
    div.style.background = "white";
    div.style.color = "#202020";
    div.style.border = "1px solid #202020";
    div.align = "center";
    div.style.marginLeft = "40%";
    div.style.fontFamily = "Lato";

    div.innerHTML =

      "<br>" +
      Student[i].club +
      "<br>" +
      "<br>" +
      Student[i].announcement +
      "<br>" +
      "<br>" +
      Student[i].gender +
      Student[i].grade +
      "<br>" +
      "<br>";

    document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: fieldann is not defined". Looks like you probably missed some code from you snippet.

Comment: why not adding class and set your properties

Comment: The error says that Student[i] is undefined. Where have you defined it? From your code it should be DOM object.

Comment: everything is defined in the rest of my code which I have not posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add student[i].club in a div and then set font weight to it.

```
"<br><div id='club'" +
Student[i].club +
"</div><br>" +
"<br>" +
Student[i].announcement +
"<br>" +
"<br>" +
Student[i].gender +
Student[i].grade +
"<br>" +
"<br>";


var club = document.getElementById('club');
club.style.fontWeight="bold";
```

Comment: Thanks, the div works, but I keep getting an error with the last 2 lines of code. Where do I put them?

Comment: but only one problem. The bold effect only works on the first time, and then it doesn't work on other Student[i].club's created by the forloop

Comment: Bold effect works for div. It doesn't work for student[i].club. For each student club you must have a div and set property. I suggest use css.

Answer (score 1):

`Student[i].grade` is not an HTML DOM element, so it does not have a `style` property and thus you can not set the `fontWeight` property.

Try setting this on a HTML DOM Element instead of string like:

```
div.style.fontWeight = "900";
```

Comment: so is there no way to individually change each Student[i] value?

Comment: Thank you very much